# Workaround for either my approach or the 256 character limit in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

My problem is as follows, I have a workbook with (to begin with) 2 worksheets, the first (called WIP) acts as a form of data entry, each new occurrence of the BoM requires an insertion of 4 columns which happens to the left of the existing columns. At the same time a new worksheet is created based on a copy of the existing second worksheet (called FitOut) which pulls various bits of a data from the first worksheet based mainly upon the version of the BoM selected and the supplier referenced.

Of course adding new columns to the WIP sheet causes the functions, arrays and formulas in the sheets to automatically update, I had used a quick workaround by using some code to hold and then paste the new occurrences data into the worksheet which is created at the start of the macro, however the formulas have become slightly complex (due to the need to look for the previous 4 occurrences and return values based on specific cell locations) that the 256 character limit has been completely shot ( I think I'm over 800 on some bits).

I've very limited as to the layout of the WIP sheet, and the sheet needs to be fairly idiot proof (hence macros, buttons etc) but it needs to run well...

ANy and all suggestions/help would be much appreciated.

I have put an example of the formula I am trying to use, if it can be condensed further pleas let me know:
*=IFERROR(IF($C$1='WIP'!$U$1,(INDEX('WIP'!$A$1:$X$2500,SMALL(IF('WIP'!$U$1:$U$2500=$A$1,ROW('WIP'!$U$1:$U$2500)),ROW(6:6)),COLUMN('WIP'!$C:$C))),(IF($C$1='WIP'!$X$1,(INDEX('WIP'!$A$1:$AA$2500,SMALL(IF('WIP'!$X$1:$X$2500=$A$1,ROW('WIP'!$X$1:$X$2500)),ROW(6:6)),COLUMN('WIP'!$C:$C))),(IF($C$1='WIP'!$AA$1,(INDEX('WIP'!$A$1:$AD$2500,SMALL(IF('WIP'!$AA$1:$AA$2500=$A$1,ROW('WIP'!$AA$1:$AA$2500)),ROW(6:6)),COLUMN('WIP'!$C:$C))),(INDEX('WIP'!$A$1:$AG$2500,SMALL(IF('WIP'!$AD$1:$AD$2500=$A$1,ROW('WIP'!$AD$1:$AD$2500)),ROW(7:7)),COLUMN('WIP'!$C:$C)))))))),"")*

Comment: You need formulae to point at the assigned columns regardless of inserted new ones? Say, to always point to 1st column and 2nd column, etc, before and after insert?

Comment: You could name the ranges, e.g. rename`U1:U2500` on your WIP sheet  to Area1 (or something that's more adequate). Then you can use `Area1` instead of `'WIP'!$U$1:$U$2500` in your formulas.

Comment: @Wujaszkun, if I understand the task correctly, there is no point in naming ranges, since the named range will move as new columns being inserted.

Comment: Try this: `=INDEX('WIP'!$C:$C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDEX('WIP'!$1:$2500,0,MATCH($C$1='WIP'!$1:$1)))/(INDEX('WIP'!$1:$2500,0,MATCH($C$1='WIP'!$1:$1))=$A$1),ROW(6:6)))`  Comments often add unprintable characters, you may need to type the whole formula if excel does not like it.

Comment: Scott's solution looks great, but I was just going to ask if you could "rotate" your data so new data gets added in rows not columns and then the formulae would work differently and not expand in the same way...

Comment: @Eugene - Not neceseraly, if you are inserting a cell/row/column inside the named range it will resize accordingly. For example if my "myRange" is L1:O12 and i add a column before let's say "N" the area "myRange" will now be L1:P12.

Comment: @Wujaszkun - If you are inserting *inside* the named range, then it's ok. But the protostar49 says he's required to insert new columns *leftmost* on the sheet, thus named range will be moved, not resized.

Comment: @Eugene - And how will current range reference behave when you add columns on the left?

Comment: @Wujaszkun Just the same way. That's why topic starter needs a solution.

Comment: @Eugene - Sorry then i though the problem to solve is the 256 char limitation for the formulas and not how they behave.

Comment: If it's possible to use the .xlsm format instead of .xls, then do so. It has a higher limit on formula lengths.